# Visual Studios Controls

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, controls, toolbox

Is there a way to download more controls or anything, because I have seen a few things in other programs I don't think I've seen in the toolbox. Can you download new ones, or did the company somehow custom make a control? If it was custom made, are there any tutorials I can take a look at that tell how to make your own?

Comment: Sorry, I just couldn't find the one, and I needed that one, and I was curious about the second question, but I didn't really need it. I figured out the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some companies make third party controls for Winforms - [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) is one I know of.

Personally, I prefer to make my own controls based on the existing WinForms ones, as I have more control over them - this prevents my products from having bugs which *just can't* be fixed. I can also tweak the controls to do exactly what I need, rather than choosing a closest match.  Building custom controls is relatively easy if you have the experience.

There is a basic tutorial on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/cutebutton.aspx) which shows how to create a *fancy* Button.  After that you should be able to figure out how to customize more complex controls.

**Side-note:**
While it's reasonably easy to develop custom controls in WinForms if you have the time to practice, WPF is a much better framework for building custom controls.  WPF controls are designed specifically for customization, so there is a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Are there any tutorials you know of?

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to look into it